# Warning "No positions in optional float specifier."

Tags: floats, positioning, warnings

I am writing a LaTeX document, and received the warning

`No positions in optional float specifier.`

However, the problem is LaTeX did not point me to where does the warning come from, therefore I could not figure out how to fix it.

Could you give me some help?

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I guess I could not provide anymore information, because as I said, there is just a warning and no indication about the reasons of warning. Anw, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It is _always_ possible to post a small complete document that generates the warning, just start with a copy of the existing document and delete everything that doesn't make the warning go away and post the resulting document in an edit to the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This is a standard latex warning. You get it when you use `\begin{figure}[]`:  `LaTeX Warning: No positions in optional float specifier.
               Default added (so using tbp) on input line 10.` (and latex adds a line number ... so it should be easy to find.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sigh. I guess I was the last person to edit the code that calls that as well, so I might have known:-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you wanna write an answer?

Answer (score 10):

This is a standard latex warning. You get it e.g. when you use `\begin{figure}[]` or `\begin{table}[]`:

```
LaTeX Warning: No positions in optional float specifier.
               Default added (so using `tbp') on input line 9.
```

And as latex adds a line number it should be easy to find.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer answer is a good one and it made me find the mistake in a document. However, in some editors (maybe only in some cases) you don't get the line error properly. In my case it was specified error at line 1 (beginning of the document) instead of line 479. In that case, your best friend could be a ctrl+F with "[]" to find the specifier problem.

Comment: Thanks for the precise response. I replaced all "[]"s with an empty string and the document was ready to go.